# How to make sense the output of DecisionTreeClassifier in scikit-learn?

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm learning ML and uses `scikit-learn` to do a basic decision tree classify.

The value of features are categorical so I used `DictVectorizer` to convert the original feature values. Here's my code:

```
training_set # list of dict representing the traing set
labels # corresponding labels of the training set
vec = DictVectorizer()
vectorized = vec.fit_transform(training_set)
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(vectorized.toarray(), labels)

with open("output.dot", "w") as output_file:
    tree.export_graphviz(clf, out_file=output_file)
```

But I don't understand the output graph. It contains a tree with each node marked `X[1] <= 0.5000` or something like that. What I expected was that the nodes marked with `FEATURE_1 == VALUE_1`, the `un-vectorized` information show on the tree.

Is it possible?

UPDATE:

For example, `FEATURE_1` has three possible values `A`, `B`, `C`, which in turn be vectorized into `0,0`, `0,1`, `1,0` respectively. What I want on the graph is `FEATURE_1 == A` instead of `X[1] <= 0.5`

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can pass the feature names to the tree exporter method:

```
with open("output.dot", "w") as output_file:
    tree.export_graphviz(clf, feature_names=vec.get_feature_names(),
                         out_file=output_file)
```

The classifier itself is unaware of the "meaning" of the data, it just deals with continuous numerical values, hence the need to use a vectorizer to one-hot-encode the categorical variables as binary variables that can safely treated as continuous variables in the range `[0, 1]` with all the actual values being either 0 or 1 and nothing in between.

To understand how the `DictVectorizer` does the one-hot-encoding, have a look at the [example snippet](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#loading-features-from-dicts) in the documentation.

Comment: We might want to add other handling of categorical variables to `DV` some day -- this question seems to pop up everywhere.

Comment: Translating string feature values to integer codes instead of separate features/columns in the resulting matrix. I.e. not doing one-of-K.

Comment: @ogrisel Can we use SKlearn to create ID3? I couldn't find an example of ID3 decision tree in its manual.

Comment: sklearn trees implement CART, see: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree-algorithms-id3-c4-5-c5-0-and-cart

Answer (score 1):

`X[1] <= 0.5000` means `X[1] = 0` if you have binary variables. If the equation holds, left branch is chosen. Otherwise, right branch. You can certainly parse the dot file and overwrite it (it's merely a text file and it's easy to do with regular expressions), but the way it is constructed initially is fixed like this, because by default the node of a tree is an inequality.

Comment: For example, `FEATURE_1` has three possible values `A`, `B`, `C`, which in turn be vectorized into `0,0`, `0,1`, `1,0` respectively. What I want on the graph is `FEATURE_1 == A` instead of `X[1] <= 0.5`

Comment: Is there more elements in X than the number of features? If feature has three possible values, then it is equivalent to 0, 1, 2 - why do you need vectors at all then?

Comment: I believe so, that's the purpose of vectorizing. Number of features are 4, and the vectorized array has 11 elements.

Comment: OK, I see, so X[1] is an element of a vector of a feature and so doesn't correspond to a particular feature at all, but rather to several possible values of features.

Comment: To be precise, `X[1]` and `X[2]` together represents `FEATURE_1`'s three possible values. Each element in `X`(together with another element in `X`) would present only one feature.

Comment: So, all in all, what you are saying is impossible because if you've split features like this, you have independent elements and you can't reconstruct features back. If you don't want it, then just keep features as discrete variables...

Comment: According to the document http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html using DictVectorizer (which uses OneHopEncoder) is the correct way to handle categorical features.

Comment: Even I uses integer to represent the categorical values, it's still confusing since the graph will give `X[1] >= 2.5` to represent `FEATURE_1 == C`

Comment: have you tried removing vectorized.toarray()? I never used this approach, so sorry can't be much help...

Answer (score 0):

When the values are in the continuous interval, the machine learner will sort the values and look for all the intermediate values to find the value with the Highest Gini index.

This is reasonable since in the continuous domain, the chance of finding a test instance with a value exactly, let's say, 3.1415 is zero. In such cases the classifier shouldn't know what to do.

I don't know about scikit-learn, but in WEKA for instance, one can specify whether the values are continue or discrete.

Comment: Yes exactly. I know `weka` and tried that for some time but just think Python would be more pleasure in learning.

Answer (score 0):

When you do an export_graphviz specify the feature_names which are the column names in this case for the independent variables DataFrame.

This would yield you the column names in your output file as below.

```
model = clf.fit(X, y)

dot_data = tree.export_graphviz(model, out_file=None, feature_names=X.columns.values.tolist(), class_names = None, filled=True, rounded=True, special_characters=True)

with open("output.dot", "w") as output_file:
    output_file.write(dot_data)
```